# ¿Cómo ejecutar una acción de un formulario en vue js?

Tags: nodejs, vue.js, express

Tengo definido el siguiente formulario y unas propiedades drag and drop de vuejs. Pero quisiera que al soltar la imagen se ejecute la acción del formulario, que está creada en el backend mediante una ruta en nodejs.

**index.ejs**

```
<form class="form" 
      id="form" 
      method="POST"
      action="/images/upload" <-- Llamar a esta acción
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      @dragover.prevent
      v-cloak @drop.prevent="addFile"
 >                            
 </form>
```

Probé de esta manera y logra imprimir por consola el elemento que he capturado, pero no sé como especificar que realize la acción definida en el formulario.

**index.ejs**

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#form',
    
    methods:{
        addFile(e) {
           file = e.dataTransfer.files[0]
           console.log(file)
           /// Llamar a action
    },
})
```

Y por último esta es la ruta a la que apunta la acción del formulario.

**index-routes.js**

```
router.post('/images/upload', (req, res) => {
    uploadImage(req, res, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            err.message = 'The file is so heavy for my service';
            return res.send(err);
        }
        console.log(req.file);
        res.send('uploaded');
    });
});
```

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: Deberias usar axios o fetch para eso....

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Entiendo que debería utilizar axios o fetch si quiero directamente crear la lógica de respuesta. Pero en mi caso el backend ya está manejando  el atributo action en el formulario. Aunque no sé como enlazar ambos. Agregué la parte del backend que controla la acción para ser más claro.

Comment: Tenes un concepto erroneo... Tu back no esta unido a tu front de ninguna manera.. los dos se hablan.. cuando en el front escribis un form, internamente va a hacer un fetch a esa url que le estas diciendo. La url esta expuesta, vos podes llamarla desde cualquier lado, no esta unido a ese form....

Comment: @gbianchi, creo que no expresé bien mi anterior respuesta. No quise decir que la url pertence exclusivamente al form que creé, pero como puedes ver la url está 'hablando' con la ruta que tiene el verbo post en ella. Realmente no sé si necesite un fetch o axios. Pensándolo bien, un llamado a un submit al agregar la imágen podría funcionar. Probaré. De nuevo gracias por responder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pude dar solución a lo que necesitaba realizar. La respuesta de @gbianchi me hizo buscar el concepto de unir el backend con el frontend, y efectivamento aquí estaba la cuestión.

Con una sencilla petición utilizando axios, pude conectar ambas partes y envíar la imágen al servidor, después de haber capturado correctamento el elemento.Comparto el código por si en un futuro pueda ser de ayuda para una novato como yo.

**index.ejs**

```
<button @click="Submit" >Submit</button>

Submit() {         
   const fd = new FormData();                
   fd.append('image', this.fileList[0])
   axios.post('/images/upload', fd, { headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }}).then(res => {
          console.log(res)
    })
}
```